# Term for maladaptive animal behavior that will lead to their demise?

Tags: terminology, animals

Moths to a flame.

Is there a term for such a behavior?

Comment: In some salmon, etc., the behavior is 'semelparity' ("the characteristic of usually mating only once in a lifetime"), or 'suicidal reproduction'. Moths are a different kettle of fish, although some moths are semelparous as well as being inadvertently suicidal by being attracted to light.

Comment: Sacrificial behaviour; self sacrifice; (both are possible leads). Wiki has a page on **Altruism (biology)** which is more promising.

Comment: IIRC the moths are simply using a naive algorithm -- they are trying to navigate by starlight, which depends on the light source being very far away, so that the moth's angle to the light source effectively never changes.  There are other insects, however, that practice autothysis -- deliberately exploding themselves, usually to protect their fellows.  Dunno if that's considered malaptive or not, but it does lead to their demise :)

Comment: From the title I would've tried to toss out *species-ending*. But that's precisely what the salmon is preventing, and with the poor moths it's just pilot error. - You're trying to find other animals that are literally like moths to a flame? ... *fatal attraction* didn't help me look. Also, lemmings *don't* commit suicide.

Comment: I found that magnets are dangerous for dogs.  Not quite at the level of moths and flames, true, but the way I found it was with `dangerous attraction animal behavior`.

Comment: 'Lemming-like' springs to mind. Try researching lemmings and see if a technical term is used of them. [Wikipedia - Lemmings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemming) just refers to 'suicide' and 'mass suicide' (which they, apparently, do not actually do). Your term 'maladaptive' sounds pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can describe them as self destructive.

Comment: I am hoping there is a specific term for the maladaptive behavior so I could look up other animals with a similar behavior.